# A function I am not using is being caught by the compiler as "not declared in scope" (c++)

Tags: c++, function, scope

First off, I've never asked a question on here so please forgive me if I haven't provided enough details or something. Please ask if you need more information and I will try to provide it. Also, please note that the majority of this code is from a college textbook(all .h files except infixToPostfix.h to be precise) that has been edited a bit.

Here is the error screen I am getting:

```
[user@penguin djrlab4]$ make
g++ lab4.cpp -o Lab4
linkedListType.h: In member function âType linkedListType<Type>::front() const [with Type = char]â:
myStack.h:45:   instantiated from âType myStack<Type>::top() const [with Type = char]â
infixToPostfix.h:65:   instantiated from here
linkedListType.h:151: error: âassertâ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [Lab4] Error 1
```

Now when I first tried to compile this, on the line it is indicating, I was using the `assert` function, but it didnt work, even after I added `#include <cassert>` so I decided to change the function instead. When I try to compile afterward, it gives that error screen as if I am still trying to use assert.. I've been trying to figure it out for a while and can't make sense of it.

I am using a g++ compiler that is on my school's server. I use a SSH client to transfer the files and compile them on their server remotely. If you need more information about the compiler, please do tell me how I should try to get it, as I have no idea..

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code here. Before you comment on how it's too long to post here, cut it down to something minimal that does what you describe.

Comment: Have you tried to `#include <assert.h>` instead?

Comment: The error messages indicate that `linkedListType.h:151` is the problem. Can you show that line (and the code surrounding it)?   Also, if you add `#include <cassert>` make sure you do this before including the non-system headers, and do `using std::assert;` before them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just compiled all your files just fine on my machine. What is probably happening is you are not correctly copying over all your files to the remote machine.

Make sure the files are correct when you compile them. If you don't have access to a GUI use `cat <filename>` to inspect its contents.

If you are running windows try [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to transfer the whole folder to your school account and run `g++ lab4.cpp` If you have a Mac you can just run g++ straight from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what the problem is. I'm not sure why it would stop transferring correctly though, since I'm doing everything the same as I always have before. I suppose I can just get a compiler for windows though and work on the assignments at home like that. Thanks again!